# Cache Storage vs Application Cache

Tags: service-worker, html5-appcache

how do we tell a browser that supports Cache Storage to ignore Application Cache? Some of the posts have mentioned that the browser ignores the html5 cache manifest. But my tests suggest otherwise.

For example, if the html page contains:

```
<html manifest="manifests/hudddle.cache">
```

and also has the **service worker** code (not shown here), I find that both sets of files are stored. I tested on Chrome 63 on Mac OS X.

Below is the image of files showing Cache Storage.

[image]

And here is the image showing Application cache.

[image]

Or am I supposed to check this on the server side and use only 1 of the two caching methods? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[mdn doc about Application Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/applicationCache) says: **Important: Application Cache is deprecated as of Firefox 44, and is no longer available in insecure contexts from Firefox 60 onwards (bug 1354175, currently Nightly/Beta only). Don't use it to offline websites — consider using service workers instead. and service workers use Cache Storage**